# Prove that $f$ is measurable.

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $u$ be a subharmonic function on the disk $\Delta$ centered at the origin with radius $\rho$.
>
> $u$ is not identically $-\infty$.
>
> Define $f:\Delta\times [0,2\pi]\rightarrow [-\infty, \infty)$ by $f(z,t)=u(ze^{it})$. Prove that $f$ is measurable.

My Try:

It suffices to prove that given $E_a=[-\infty, a)$, $a\in \mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}(E_a)$ is measurable in $\Delta\times [0,2\pi]$.
$f^{-1}(E_a)=\{(z,t)\in \Delta\times [0,2\pi]; u(ze^{it})<a\}$. Since $u$ is subharmonic on $\Delta$ it is upper semicontinuous on it. Thus $U=\{ze^{it}\in \Delta ;u(ze^{it})<a\}$ is open in $\Delta$. Now I wanted to prove that $f^{-1}(E_a)$ is open in $\Delta\times [0,2\pi]$ in order to show it is measurable. I know that it is not necessary to show it is open, but I thought it is the easiest way. But failed to prove it. Can anyone please help me to proceed?

Comment: You just said that $U$ is open, and you know that $ze^it$ is continuous w.r.t. $z$ and $t$, I believe you can proof that f is upper semicontinuous too.